# Git branch ahead of master (old repo)

Tags: git

I get annoyed with the fact that every time I checkout to my master branch I get the message that my branch is ahead of my old repository.

A while ago I created a new repository I renamed that one to origin and renamed the other one to old but now every time that I checkout to my master to merge the current branch I get this annoying message that my master is behind on the old repository.

I do not want to get rid of the repository completely as I might need it on a later time

Does anyone have an idea how to git rid of this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git issues this warning only when a branch is ahead of the one *it is tracking*. This means you not only see this warning but also experience some other inconveniences working with your `master` branch since it is tracking an obsolete one.

You should set the branch to track `master` in the *new* repository:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally no more unnecessary messages  :D